# Rewrite method to remove items from index and subtracting all remaining items numbers in index by 1

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I need to rewrite method to remove items from index and subtracting all remaining items numbers in index by 1.

Including the above condition, I need to rewrite "getLot" so it doesn't rely on index numbers to find lots. It should only find lots according to their lot number. So if lot number 2 is removed, then lot 3 will move from index 2 to index 1 and still be found as lot 3, and not by index 2 which it is no longer. (index starts at 0 btw)

Here is my code:

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
{
    if((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {
        // The number seems to be reasonable.
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);
        // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
        // right lot.
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                               selectedLot.getNumber() +
                               " was returned instead of " +
                               lotNumber);
            // Don't return an invalid lot.
            selectedLot = null;
        }
        return selectedLot;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                           " does not exist.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I retagged the question, as this doesn't appear to have anything to do with JavaScript.  If someone can think of a better tag to use...

Comment: why not use linkedlist

Answer (score 1):

you can use [commons lang's](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//download_lang.cgi) `ArrayUtils` as:

`array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two approach

**Approach 1** :instead of Using Array you can adapt your code to use ArrayList.

```
String[] lotArray;
List<String> lotList =  Arrays.asList(lotArray);

lotList.remove("Lot 2");
```

**Approach 2** : [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) from [CommonLang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//download_lang.cgi)

```
 array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)
```